# What is the simplest way to round a floating point number up to the next integer in Python?

Tags: python

I have been writing a program for a project and have tried using the round() function to round a floating point variable up to the next whole number.  In the case of this program, it calculates how much paint is required (in gallons) to paint a certain amount of square footage.  The exercise assumes that paint is only available in whole gallons, so my calculation needs to round up all fractions of a gallon to the next whole gallons.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: I tried reading through that post, but the answers were not really clear to me and I wasn't able to find a solution based on the information provided.  PLEASE be assured that I did a LOT of searching before I asked the question :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.  Apparently I need to import the math module into my program.  When I read the Python documentation, it stated that the math module was always available.  Now that I have added "import math" to the beginning of my program, I am not getting the syntax error.

If anyone is interested in the syntax I used, here is the code:

```
def calculateGallonsNeeded(fltWallArea,AREA_UNIT):
    fltGallonsNeeded = math.ceil(fltWallArea / AREA_UNIT)
    return fltGallonsNeeded
```

Thanks for all the help.

Scott

Comment: For the record, not importing `math` should not have given you a `SyntaxError`.  It might have given you a `NameError`, though.  On another subject, what the docs mean by `math` always being available isn't that you don't have to import it, it's that it's not a platform-dependent module.

Answer (score 7):

Use `math.ceil()`:

```
print math.ceil(3.4)
# 4.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried adding the function to my program and I am getting a syntax error.  Here is the line: "fltPaintCost = math.ceil(calculatePaintCost(fltPaintPrice,fltPaintNeeded))"

Comment: Please post all relevant code and an exact copy of the error message in your question.

Comment: Did you remember to put `import math` at the top of your program?